# "User 0" message displayed on notification bar of android KitKat

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, navigation-bar

I recently upgraded my Lenovo P780 to kitkat and yesterday applied an update from Lenovo "P780_ROW_8G_S222_140817". After applying this update, I have started seeing text "User 0" in the notification bar (next to the setting icons on right top corner) and additionally, U0 text is displayed in the notification area below the icons.
I am not able to cppture screen for the notification area hence unableto attach the screenshot.
Does anyone have any idea on how to remove this text or is this a bug with the new update?

Comment: Do you have a Google account set? It might be that the upgrade included multi-user support but your username isn't set. It should happen automatically if you have a Google account.

Comment: Are you the same person who [asked this the other day](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/80943/12442)? To add more details to a question, you need to log in as the same user and click "edit". Creating more and more questions for the same issue just causes confusion and makes it harder to find information.

Comment: @Dan- I created my account few hours back. It might be some other user.

Comment: @ Onik - I do have a google account set. Though can you let me know how do I confirm the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **"feature"** on the update for the Lenovo P780 I'm afraid. Other users are reporting the same issue (amongst others) with the device.

**User 0** is the "first" user on the device, i.e. the "administrator" profile. You could then add subsequent profiles (1, 2, 3) etc for other users of the device. This information is not usually displayed.

You can read the  [support thread here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Phones/Lenovo-P780-preOTA-IMEI-collection-through-email-for-privacy/td-p/1677721/page/1)  on Lenovo's support forum.

Example:

Post from Kannanovo (user on Lenovo forum)

> I have "User 0" and "U0" in the notification bar i don't know whether this is an issue,

And there are others there.

The reply from Lenovo, last dated the 22th August 2014 (which is the date I'm writing this) follows (from  [page 7](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Phones/Lenovo-P780-preOTA-IMEI-collection-through-email-for-privacy/td-p/1677721/page/7) )

> Hello there,
>
> Thank you for all your information. 
>   We are analysising all the issues received, some of you might have received separate email or message for further information. Please do help us to collect the details, that is very important for us to root cause your issues and provide correct fix in further update. 
>   please drop you issues here or email me. We will work hard and try our best to give our customer best experience. 
>   Thank you for your patience and cooperation.
>
> Wang

As Dan mentioned  [another user posted a similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/80943/user-0-on-notification-screen)  without enough detail so I would imagine this new 'feature' is common enough.